# ImportError: no module named PIL when opening the .py file directly in Windows

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, py2exe

This is a rather complicated problem.

My Python script uses the module PIL which is loaded by:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

The script works fine in the IDE and also when I start it from the cmd:

```
python script.py
```

But when I try to open it by double-clicking it gives the ImportError: no module named PIL. I'm using python 2.7 in Anaconda. I uninstalled PIL and installed Pillow, but the problem persists. I copied the PIL directory to the working directory, but then I get ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I also need to compile it as an executable, but opening the executable gives yet another error: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.18, need exactly 8.5.15.

It compiles just fine when I leave out the part of the script that uses PIL. Is there any way to have my cake and eat it too - to use images in the tkinter interface AND compile it with py2exe?

Comment: I'd guess you're not using the same Python interpreter when you double click on the `.py` file as you are when you run from the command line.

Comment: To find what interpreter you are running, put `import sys; print(sys.executable)` in your code before the import.  `print(sys.path)` shows where pillow is being looked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the double-click was indeed using a different interpreter. The double click used the 32-bit python version in Program Files (x86) whereas opening it via command line by typing in python script.py used the 64-bit python version in the Anaconda installation directory. Apparently I had installed python from python.org, then had forgotten all about it and installed Anaconda. Changing the file associations fixed the issue, thank you for your help guys.