# Trouble changing the Python Interpreter in Windows

Tags: python, windows, interpreter

So I have some code, it runs fine in my IDE (PyCharm) as it is using the correct interpreter (Anaconda2).

I can run the program from CMD by typing `python myProgram.py` and this uses the correct interpreter, but I need the program to run on double click, yet when I do this it gives an error and immediately shuts down.

[image: The error when running]

This is almost definitely down to it using the wrong interpreter, even when I right click and select 'Open With' and select the same python.exe that my IDE is using it gives the same error.

My windows Environmental Variables include Anaconda as the path, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8jEt.png)

I have tried:

- What was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904170/the-wrong-python-interpreter-is-called), adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` but this did not work.
- As mentioned before, what was mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787195/importerror-no-module-named-pil-when-opening-the-py-file-directly-in-windows), to no avail.

How can I make sure my program is always run using a specific interpreter? Specifically when double clicking to run it?

Thanks

Comment: Do not post text as image, copy it instead.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/310335/how-do-i-change-the-file-association-to-a-program-with-the-same-name-in-windows

Comment: Make sure that `Python.File` is set to run the right python.exe, e.g. `"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*`, or if Python 3 is installed with the new launcher, it should be `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*` if you installed the launcher for all users.

Comment: The link that ivan_pozdeev posted fixed my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `#!/usr/bin/env python` (this is called a shebang) does not work is that that is a feature of the linux shell, bash (a shell is a program that you use to input commands, like `cmd.exe` on windows)

As for the answer, try looking in the build/run configurations of your IDE and look at what command is being run from there. Also, you should add the anaconda directory to the system path, not the user one, and I think path needs a capital P

Comment: [Nowadays, it's a feature of Linux kernel.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Comment: I added the Anaconda directory to the system path. My run settings look like [this](http://puu.sh/nGoPq/35fed1ee4c.png).

All that I can gather from that is that it is using the interpreter I want it to...

Comment: Shebangs work if Python 3 is installed and the .py association is configured to use the py.exe launcher that handles virtual shebang paths such as `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/env python` (to search `PATH`  for python.exe). These virtual paths are supported to run cross-platform scripts on Windows, and they default to running the latest installed version of Python 2 since `python` generally means Python 2 on Unix systems.

Answer (score 1):

If your python interpreter is named the same in your anaconda installation as your original python2.7 installation, you are going to have problems. Try renaming one of them. Like calling python in your python2.7 installation python2.

**Edit**
In order for the response not to be to long of a comment, I make this an edit.

If you run it from cmd you can specify interpreter.

```
<interpreter-name> yourfile.py
```

However when setting default program to run your python files, it will be the same from everyone. Thus you need to specify with cmd if you want to run it with a different interpreter.

Comment: This semi works, when I double click it asks me to choose a program to run it with every time (I can't choose it as default), then it works. How can I make it default to that other interpreter?